# How can I get files to load in my current detached editor in eclipse juno?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

So it seems very random which view a new file opens up in.  I would like to be able to select something like a "main view" which would be the current detached editor I'm working in and have all my files open in that view.  Does anyone know how to do this?